# How to set session timezone for ClickHouse jdbc connection?

Tags: jdbc, clickhouse

Can I do it?  For example, so it looks like in Postgres:

```
set timezone 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be such function as of yet.

It seems that there isn't even such thing as a session timezone, only the server timezone:
https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/issues/699

And there is no such setting in the settings table:
`select * from system.settings where name like '%zone%'`

As a workaround you can specify TZ explicitly in the function calls:

`toString(now(), 'Asia/Yekaterinburg')` or `toDate(time, 'Asia/Yekaterinburg')`